# Winbug error made use of undefined node d

Tags: compilation, winbugs

I seek to edit the downloaded network meta-analysis model with my own data, it runs fine until I compile the model after loading my data. Winbugs warn that "made use of undefined node d". I try to sort it out, but I failed. Please help me. The model and my data showed as follow.

```js
# Binomial likelihood, logit link, inconsistency model
# Random effects model
model{                      # *** PROGRAM STARTS
for(i in 1:ns){             # LOOP THROUGH STUDIES
    delta[i,1]<-0           # treatment effect is zero in control arm
    mu[i] ~ dnorm(0,.0001)  # vague priors for trial baselines
    for (k in 1:na[i])  {   # LOOP THROUGH ARMS
        r[i,k] ~ dbin(p[i,k],n[i,k]) # binomial likelihood
        logit(p[i,k]) <- mu[i] + delta[i,k]  # model for linear predictor
#Deviance contribution
        rhat[i,k] <- p[i,k] * n[i,k] # expected value of the numerators 
        dev[i,k] <- 2 * (r[i,k] * (log(r[i,k])-log(rhat[i,k]))  
          +  (n[i,k]-r[i,k]) * (log(n[i,k]-r[i,k]) - log(n[i,k]-rhat[i,k])))   
      }
# summed residual deviance contribution for this trial
   resdev[i] <- sum(dev[i,1:na[i]])
   for (k in 2:na[i]) {  # LOOP THROUGH ARMS
# trial-specific LOR distributions
        delta[i,k] ~ dnorm(d[t[i,1],t[i,k]] ,tau) 
      }
  }   
totresdev <- sum(resdev[])   # Total Residual Deviance
for (c in 1:(nt-1)) {  # priors for all mean treatment effects
    for (k in (c+1):nt)  { d[c,k] ~ dnorm(0,.0001) } 
  }  
sd ~ dunif(0,5)  # vague prior for between-trial standard deviation
var <- pow(sd,2) # between-trial variance
tau <- 1/var     # between-trial precision
} # *** PROGRAM ENDS


# ns= number of studies; nt=number of treatments
list(nt=13,ns=17)   
t[,1]   t[,2]   t[,3]   t[,4]   r[,1]   r[,2]   r[,3]   r[,4]   n[,1]   n[,2]   n[,3]   n[,4]   na[]    #   study
9   3   7   11  9   8   6   7   20  16  14  15  4   #   1
9   7   8   NA  117 83  122 NA  229 231 247 NA  3   #   2
9   3   NA  NA  8   3   NA  NA  18  13  NA  NA  2   #   3
9   5   NA  NA  13  16  NA  NA  20  20  NA  NA  2   #   4
9   1   2   NA  105 103 165 NA  226 228 227 NA  3   #   5
9   2   13  NA  30  67  52  NA  96  200 195 NA  3   #   6
9   6   NA  NA  7   7   NA  NA  17  18  NA  NA  2   #   7
7   12  NA  NA  5   2   NA  NA  14  12  NA  NA  2   #   8
9   7   8   12  14  8   12  8   24  23  21  26  4   #   9
9   8   NA  NA  5   12  NA  NA  30  34  NA  NA  2   #   10
9   10  NA  NA  3   10  NA  NA  25  25  NA  NA  2   #   11
9   3   4   11  12  8   17  8   22  24  25  26  4   #   12
9   8   NA  NA  8   17  NA  NA  21  24  NA  NA  2   #   13
1   7   NA  NA  9   4   NA  NA  15  15  NA  NA  2   #   14
9   1   NA  NA  8   1   NA  NA  30  29  NA  NA  2   #   15
9   3   11  NA  3   5   0   NA  21  23  8   NA  3   #   16
9   8   NA  NA  13  15  NA  NA  19  16  NA  NA  2   #   17





END
list(d=c( NA, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), sd=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when trying the run an inconsistency model as well, it was really annoying at first because it was really difficult to spot where the issue was. In fact, if you look at the third block of your WinBUGS code, you didn't define priors for some nodes such as d[9,1], d[9,2]...d[9,8]; this is the reason why the error message keeps popping up.

fixing this issue is then straightforward. In the inconsistency model, t[,1] should always be lower than t[,2] and t[,2] should always be lower than t[,3] and so on.

I hope it helps...